# How to programmatically getting link to CSV behind javascript page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using python and I'm trying to get the link from which the CSV come from when I click on the `DATA V CSV` button at the bottom of [this page](https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data#AktualniSystemovaOdchylkaCR).

I tried `beautifulsoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data#AktualniSystemovaOdchylkaCR'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the link to the CSV file
csv_link = soup.find('a', string='DATA V CSV').get('href')
```

I also tried:

`soup.find("button", {"id":"DATA V CSV"})`

but it doesn't find the link behind `DATA V CSV`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get **all** data you need to fully mimic the requests that are send to the server.

Here's how to do it:

```py
from shutil import copyfileobj
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data",
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "cookie": "nette-samesite=1; ARRAffinity=3ee2404f26d0149d946e50cb3d4c22661f9f3b6510837fa538c67990a81979de; ARRAffinitySameSite=3ee2404f26d0149d946e50cb3d4c22661f9f3b6510837fa538c67990a81979de"
}

payload = {
    "do": "loadGraphData",
    "method": "AktualniSystemovaOdchylkaCR",
    "graph_id": "1026",
    "move_graph": "day",
    "download": "csv",
    "date_to": "2023-03-28T23:59:59",
    "date_from": "2023-03-28T00:00:00",
    "agregation": "MI",
    "date_type": "day",
    "interval": "false",
    "version": "bla",
    "function": "AVG",
}

all_data = "https://www.ceps.cz/en/all-data"
download_url = "https://www.ceps.cz/download-data/?format=csv"

with requests.Session() as s:
    headers.update({"x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"})
    r = s.get(f"{all_data}?{urlencode(payload)}", headers=headers)
    print(r.json()["result"])
    headers.pop("x-requested-with")
    with s.get(download_url, headers=headers, stream=True) as r, \
            open("data.csv", "wb") as f:
        copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

You should get a `semicolon`-separated file that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Really good answer. Could you explain a bit about why you use `requests.session` instead of calling the `requests.get` directly? And why `update` and then `pop` of the headers? Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer! How does this work technically? As far as I can tell the only thing that could change between the two requests is the session object... is there a cookie being added after the first request which tells it to get that specific data (`AktualniSystemovaOdchylkaCR`)?? I'm trying to understand what would be going on in the backend

Comment: @Joshua I'm using the [session object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) to persist some parameters across the two requests and I'm modifying the headers to replicate what's happening when you observe the Network tab in the Developers Tool in your browser.  First, we tell what type of data file we want and in what format. Then, resuing the session, we download the generated file.

Answer (score 0):

The site dynamically generates a link. With the help of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, you can’t pull it out. On using the browser debugger, you can easily find it manually by clicking on the button and looking at what calls are being made.

```
import requests


url = 'https://www.ceps.cz/download-data/?format=csv'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)

--------------------------

Data version;From;To;Agregation function;Agregation;Type of power plant;
real data;28.03.2023 09:00:00;28.03.2023 09:59:59;agregation average;minute;ALL;
Date;WPP [MW];PVPP [MW];
28.03.2023 09:00;189.8;342.3;
28.03.2023 09:01;194.1;342.3;
28.03.2023 09:02;200.1;354.4;
28.03.2023 09:03;200.1;366.3;
28.03.2023 09:04;200.1;383.4;
28.03.2023 09:05;197.5;387.4;
28.03.2023 09:06;195.4;391.4;
28.03.2023 09:07;198.2;398.3;
28.03.2023 09:08;198.2;388.9;
28.03.2023 09:09;199.6;397.2;
28.03.2023 09:10;205.1;400.8;
28.03.2023 09:11;205.1;410.8;
28.03.2023 09:12;203.1;413.1;
28.03.2023 09:13;198.6;413.1;
28.03.2023 09:14;198.6;413.1;
```

Comment: the Using the 'browser debugger' is where I had problem with